# Loading Old Bundle in React native . While running on Physical device

Tags: react-native

While trying to run generated build apk  or debugging on physical device , It is loading old bundle. and not reflecting any changes, it Happens only with physical device on same network.

Following tricks are not working for me.
1.

```
 Run the command in a terminal: ps ax | grep react-native
    Kill all processes and run bundle script again.
```

2.

```
 rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*
```

3.

```
--resetCache true
```

4.

```
--reset-cache
```

5.

```
Permanent delete node_modules
npm cache clean –force
npm install
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Story Starts Here.
[image: Unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle']

Was getting error while loading on physical device.

So, For fixing it. 
Had to follow the below lines in project root folder

```
mkdir android/app/src/main/assets

react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

react-native run-android
```

From second time on wards ,need to execute  following code  for updating the bundle before loading into physical device

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to clean your current build.
`cd android && ./gradlew clean`
`cd .. && react-native run-android`

Also delete the current generated APK inside the outputs/apk folder inside android.

And if you are using windows, try running the terminal window as administrator.

Comment: Yes, I'm windows user. It's not working .
Still returns old bundle output. not reflecting any changes

Comment: Try uninstalling the app from emulator, or wipe data on emulator and see if it fixes this. I am not sure what's going on, just a suggestion.

Comment: No trouble with emulator, It works fine. the problem is while running on physical device only

Comment: I have no clue whats going on. Did you try installing the bundle in another android device?

Comment: I fixed it and found the solution for it!

Comment: Awesome! Can you post the solution using 'Answer your own question' feature?

Comment: Sure. You can find the answer below

Answer (score 0):

try this command

```
curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"
```

and after that run again following command

```
react-native run-android
```

Comment: I see this is also another way to update the bundle for android.

Comment: But the above command will return error for me since my entry file is 
index.js and not index.android .js ..

Answer (score 0):

These are the correct steps that worked for me in order to manually build the bundle and install it on the device, been scratching my head for hours until I managed to find how to do this properly:

```
cd android

./gradlew clean

cd ../

react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

./gradlew assembleRelease

./gradlew installRelease
```